# Javascript set Cookie to get value in a dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

Hi guys how do we do this?

for example i have a list of dropdown

```
<select>
  <option>OPT 1</option>
  <option>OPT 2</option>
  <option>OPT 3</option>
</select>
```

and then i have 3 different a hrefs

```
<a href="go to some url">SHOWS OPT 1</a>
<a href="go to some url">SHOWS OPT 2</a>
<a href="go to some url">SHOWS OPT 3</a>
```

now how can we set the cookie for this using javascript? when the user selects a href SHOWS OPT 1 it will select the OPT 1 in the select dropdown list, then it will get the cookies stored in the OPT 1

Comment: What do you mean by "then it will get the cookies stored in the OPT 1"?

Comment: hi @plbsam, this is what i would like to happen User clicks on dynamic nav link(which are the ahref) > Cookie is set > Page Loads > Webpart pulls out content based on cookie value

Answer (score 0):

You may add onclick events to your html links to set cookies,

```
<a href="go to some url" onclick="document.cookie='OPT=1'">SHOWS OPT 1</a>
<a href="go to some url" onclick="document.cookie='OPT=2'">SHOWS OPT 2</a>
<a href="go to some url" onclick="document.cookie='OPT=3'">SHOWS OPT 3</a>
```

Then to read cookies 
you may use this js function,

```
function readCookie(cookieName){
  var re = new RegExp('[; ]'+cookieName+'=([^\\s;]*)');
  var sMatch = (' '+document.cookie).match(re);
  return (cookieName && sMatch)? unescape(sMatch[1]):'';  
}
```

and then read cookie with,

```
readCookie('OPT');
```

As an alternative to using cookies directly, You can use **HTML5 local storage**.
A brief description of the local storage can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)